# custom UITableViewController cell segue not pushing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, segue

I have a custom UITableViewController showing a TableView with a list of locations, I created a segue in the storyboard (ios 5) and gave it an Identifier "SelectPlace", it's coming out of a cell in the first UITableViewController and is supposed to segue to the next UITableViewController showing a new tableview with a list of details of the location chosen.

Problem is the segue does not perform (next TableViewController is not pushed into screen, current one stays on) even though I double checked for the correct identifier and set everything in place.
I even see (breakpoints) the -prepareForSegue happening and completing successfully.

I also tried adding

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SelectPlace" sender:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

to the cell selection

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but it did not help (and I don't think it's neccasary because the segue is drawn on the storyboard)

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog([segue.identifier description]);
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SelectPlace"])
    {
        NSArray* placePhotosArr = [FlickrFetcher photosInPlace:[self.topPlacesArray objectAtIndex:([self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row)] maxResults:50];
        [segue.destinationViewController setPlacePhotosArray:placePhotosArr];

        //[segue perform];
        NSLog([placePhotosArr description]);        

    }
}
```

what's missing???
please help

Comment: Your above code helped fix my issue.  Thanks for posting back what you did wrong! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, the reason the segue was not pushing was because I forgot to 'embed' the tableviewcontroller in a navigation viewcontroller... duh

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will make a difference but I use this implementation:

```
[[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"]
```

and is it a push or what type of transition are you using

Comment: Yea, it's push. but it's never getting displayed.. I can't understand why.
btw, no difference between the two notations since identifier is a property in class segue.

Comment: segue.identifier is the property notation of [segue identifier], there is no functional difference between those two notations